# Get-Credential for IIS FTP User with Virtual Host Name Prefix?

Tags: powershell, security, iis, ftp

Our third-party IIS team provides IIS FTP usernames with a virtual host name prefix. For example: "x.y.z.com|Username" (note the pipe separator).

Running PowerShell Get-Credential command:

```
Get-Credential | Export-Clixml {FILEPATH}
```

and then providing "User name" = "x.y.z.com|Username" into the pop-up window provides this tooltip error:

```
Examples: 
User Name 
username@domain 
DOMAIN\
```

I can manually generate secure strings and import/export, but I'd like to have a simple out-of-the-box way to store this credential.

Some background:
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.ftpserver/serverruntime/hostnamesupport
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround which doesn't use Get-Credential:

```
(New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
            -ArgumentList (Read-Host "Please enter the user name"), `
            (Read-Host -assecurestring "Please enter the password")) | 
Export-CliXml "FILEPATH"
```

Verifying the password:

```
(New-Object PSCredential "dummyuserignore", `
(Import-CliXml "FILEPATH").Password).GetNetworkCredential().Password
```